# modify pickup and delivery problem to only delivery scenario in google OR-tools

Tags: optimization, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am using Google OR Tools for solving the capacitated vehicle routing problem.I want to implement optimization solution for delivery problem.For example there is one storage location which load all packages to multiple trucks which have multiple capacities. These trucks should deliver packages (no pickup) minimizing the total distance.
In [OR-tools documentation there is a example for pickup and delivery problem](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrp),I am not able to modify this example for only delivery problem.

Comment: If you only have delivery, then you are dealing with a "classical" CVRP and [this](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrp) should work.

Comment: Dear @Rajith Thennakoon, Routing Problems can be classified and pictured in several and distinct models depending on adopted hypothesis/assumptions.
Starting from simplest (TSP) the available models are
TSP-Traveling Salesman Problem, VRP-Vehicle Routing Problem, CVRP-Capacited Vehicle Routing Problem

Comment: ECVRP-Equal Capacited Vehicle Routing Problem, UCVRP-Capacited Vehicle Routing Problem with Unequal Demands, VRPSB-Vehicle Routing Problem with Simultaneous Backhauls, VRPSPD-Vehicle Routing Problem with Simultaneous Pick-up and Delivery,
VRPB-Vehicle Routing Problem with Backhauls, VRPPD-Vehicle Routing Problem with Pick-up and Delivery,VRPTW-Vehicle Routing Problem with Time Window constraints. I am not confident with OR-tools, but in case I could give you a more detailed description of CVRP in terms of mathematical formulation of your problem